# How to tell if a name is a tag, bookmark, or named branch?

Tags: mercurial, branch

Given a nice string labe that works with `hg show` (ex: `hg show stable`), how can I determine if `stable` is a tag name, a bookmark name, or a named branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In core hg, `hg show` will show **nothing** about repository, because

- "show" command is shorthand for "showconfig", which, in turn, is alias for "config"
- `hg config` is used for

> show combined config settings from all hgrc files

only

2. If you have *any* id, related to some unknown changeset in repository, you can always get **full details** about this changeset, using ordinary `hg log -r <ID>` even with default template

Id is tag

```
>hg log -r 0.2.4
changeset:   358:b53421918a89
tag:         0.2.4
...
```

Id is bookmark

```
>hg log -r mainline
changeset:   1195:b800644fcbe2
bookmark:    mainline
…
```

The same results will appear for topics|branches, I just haven't samples now